# web3.eth.sendTransacton- callback not woriking as expected

Tags: transactions, web3js

When I use

```
eth.sendTransaction({
to:eth.accounts[0],
from: eth.accounts[1], 
value:web3.toWei(1099807516000000000000,"ether")
});
```

I get error like :

```
Error: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

The error is expected because I was trying to transfer more ethers than I have in my account.

But, when I try using same on web3 like:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:to, from:from, value:web3.toWei(amount,"ether")},function( _erro,_respo){
  if(_erro){
    console.log("Error is "+_erro)
  }
  else{
    console.log("Transaction is="+_respo);
   return res.json({"success":"true","data":[{transactionId:_respo}]});
}
});
```

And when I call this function with the **same set of data**, I don't get any error. Instead, I get a transaction hash.

The expected behavior was to see an error. Why is this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Try specifying the gas price manually. web3.js may have a different default. Also, double-check that the addresses are the same, and that the behaviour repeats. (eg the first payment you send to a new account costs more gas, so the operation order can make a difference.)

Comment: No, it's not related to specifying the amount of gas. I am trying to send more ethers than I have in my account, so in any case I must get an error. But I'm not getting any while using web3.